# How to solve this in java?

Tags: java

My program gets as input parameter a String containing a list of IP Addresses. Each IP address is separated by a line break. It can look like this:

```
10.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
11.1.1.1
```

it can look like this

```
10.1.1.1-20
1.1.1.1
```

but it can looki like this

```
172.16.12.1-20 /24
10.1.1.1
```

I want to check every IP address and return two Lists validAddresses, invalidAddresses.

I've already wrote a program that deals with the first the simplest type of input, i.e. no IP address ranges and no network masks.

```
private String[] extractIPAddress(String address){
    String[] temp;
    temp = address.split("\\s+");
    return temp;
}
```

Then I do

```
addressList = extractIPAddress(String.valueOf(value));

for (int i=0; i < addressList.length; i++) {
    if (InetAddresses.isInetAddress(addressList[i]) == true) {
        validAddress = validAddress.concat(addressList[i] + '\n');
    } else {
        invalidAddress = invalidAddress.concat(addressList[i] + '\n');
    }
}
```

Now I'm pondering how to deal with the most complex type of input, esp.

- when the line has a range attached to it `1.1.1.1-10`, how to remove the `-10` part in order check the main IP address; how to check whether range part `-10` would make a valid IP address i.e. `1.1.1.10` and then how to put everything together, so I can return it as a line of the `validAddress` String, looking the same way as at the beginning, i.e. `1.1.1.1-10`
- same question applies to the network mask `/24`

What elements would this kind of program have? Could you outline it for me?

I thought I would do the following, but I'm not sure if that's the right way and how to implement some parts:

- if I find a `-` then cut off the part starting at the position of `-` until end of line or "/" (how to do that?)
- save that part into the `ipRange` variable
- if I find `/` then cut off that part starting at the position of `/` until the end of the line
- save that part into `netMask` variable
- copy the content into the `tmp_ipRange = ipRange`
- remove the `-` in the `tem_ipRange` variable
- replace the last octet of the main IP address with `tmp_ipRange` (how to do that?)
- add the new IP address to the array created by the `String.split()` (impossible, because you can't just add something to an array in java? what alternative do I have? so I can't use split here?)
- loop through the `addressList` (see above code) and check if the IP address is a valid IP address
- after the validation add `ipRange` to the main `ipAddress` if `ipRange` is not `null` (how do I find the main `ipAddress` the `ipRange` belongs to?)
- after the validation add `netMaske` to the main `ipAddress` (and range) if `mainAddress` is not `null` (how do I find the main `ipAddress` the `netMask` belongs to?)

Comment: You might want to break this up into several smaller questions. It's quite long at the moment.

Comment: Woo hoo... too much to handle :)

Comment: feel free to answer a part of it

Comment: tl;dr and "*How to solve this in java*" is not a good question title.

Comment: @user1329572 I hear a great suggestion coming... :-)

Comment: @Thomas: It's your job to improve the question, not ours.

Comment: `Processing a list of IP addresses with ranges and netmasks` would be a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I wrote the following code to tackle this task. The code is working as expected. Since this is one of my first java programs at all, I was wondering if you see any issues in this code?:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.System;

import com.google.common.net.InetAddresses;

public class IPCheck{

  public static String[] extractLine(String line){
    String[] temp;
    temp = line.split("\\s+");

    return temp;
  }

  public static boolean hasNetMask(String line){
    boolean result = false;
    if(line.indexOf("/") != -1)
    result = true;

    return result;
  }

  public static boolean hasIPRange(String line){
    boolean result = false;
    if(line.indexOf("-") != -1)
    result = true;

    return result;
  }

  public static String extractNetMask(String line){
    String result = "";
    result = line.substring(line.indexOf("/"));

    return result;
  }

  public static String extractIPRange(String line){
    String result = "";
    result = line.substring(line.indexOf("-"));

    return result;
  }

  public static String chop(String line, String piece){
    String result = "";
    result = line.replace(piece, "");

    return result;
  }

  public static boolean validateIPRange(String ipRange){
    int tmpInt = 0;
    ipRange = chop(ipRange, "-");
    tmpInt = Integer.valueOf(ipRange);
    if(tmpInt > 255)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    String validIPAddress = "";
    String invalidIPAddress = "";
    String str = "10.1.1.1-300\n192.180.0.1-10/16\n192.168.0.1111";
    String[] addressList;
    String netMask = "";
    String ipRange = "";

    addressList = extractLine(str);
    for(int i=0; i<addressList.length; i++){

    if(hasNetMask(addressList[i]) == true){
      netMask = extractNetMask(addressList[i]);
      addressList[i] = chop(addressList[i], netMask);
    }

    if(hasIPRange(addressList[i]) == true){
      ipRange = extractIPRange(addressList[i]);
      addressList[i] = chop(addressList[i], ipRange);

       if(validateIPRange(ipRange) == false){
        /*if the IPRange is not valid, let's attach the ipRange
        to the current IP-Address to make it invalid*/
        addressList[i] = addressList[i].concat(ipRange);
        System.out.println( addressList[i]);
       }
    }

    if(InetAddresses.isInetAddress(addressList[i]) == true){
      validIPAddress = validIPAddress.concat(addressList[i] + ipRange + netMask);
    } else {
      invalidIPAddress = invalidIPAddress.concat(addressList[i] + ipRange + netMask);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The parsing part could be done by a regular expression. Something like:

```java
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)(?:-(\\d+))?(?:/(\\d+))?" );
for(String line : new String [] { "172.16.12.1-20/24",
                                  "172.16.12.1-20", 
                                  "172.16.12.1/24", 
                                  "172.16.12.1" })
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String address = m.group(1);
        String rangePart = m.group(2); // is null if there is no range part
        String netmask = m.group(3); // is null if there is no netmask
        System.out.println(address + " - " + rangePart + " - " + netmask);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** If you need to deal with spaces, you can augment the regular expression by adding `\\s*`, for example:

```java
"\\s*(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)(?:\\s*-\\s*(\\d+))?(?:\\s*/\\s*(\\d+))?\\s*"
```

This way, you won't need to bother with spaces.

You could also create a similar regular expression for IPv6 addresses. It will be longer, of course, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Nice, I assume I would pass the address part to the split() function, but then lose the track of which part of rangePart and netmask belongs to what IP... Then I also have to deal with IPv6 addresses which do not build on x.x.x.x but also have no range nor mask part.